# simplest home streaming server php alphabetization

Tags: php, echo, media-player, media, alphabetical-sort

this is the code im using:

```
<?php

        $dir = "House Of Cards/";
        $videoW = 320;
        $videoH = 240;

        if (is_dir($dir))
        {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)){

                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

                    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){

                        echo "
                        <div style='display: block'>
                        <a href= \"$dir/$file\">Watch \"$file\"</a>
                        </div>
                        ";


                    }

                }

                closedir($dh);

              }
        };
        ?>
```

im attempting to host a tiny simple http server with php on my router so i can stream videos to my phone while i work

basically, i have a index.php with in every folder that has videos

this works fine, when the video is encoded right, but when it lists the videos in the folder theyre not "alphabetized" or non-sequential

they come up like this:

```
Watch "House Of Cards S01E01.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E08.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E05.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E11.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E03.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E10.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E02.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E07.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E09.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E13.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E12.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E04.mp4"
Watch "House Of Cards S01E06.mp4"
```

anyone know how i can make this code turn up asequential or "alphabetized" list?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look here: [natsort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Essentially this function will use an algorithm to sort your files in a "natural" order, instead of alphabetical as it is now.

To add onto your code, you could add all your files into an array when looping through files in the directory, and at the end, run natsort, before printing links for each of them.

```
<?php

    $dir = "House Of Cards/";
    $videoW = 320;
    $videoH = 240;

    $files = []; // Initialize empty array

    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    $files[] = $file; // add this file to array
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

    natsort($files); // naturally sort files

    // make a link for each file...
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        echo "<div style='display: block'>
             <a href= \"$dir/$file\">Watch \"$file\"</a>
             </div>";
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this worked perfectly. with very little modification. (theres an extra "}" id upvote this answer you if i could

Comment: Oh, my bad, removed that extra "}" :)

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (is_dir($dir))
        {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)){

                while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

                    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
                            $files[] = $file;
                    }

                }

                closedir($dh);

              }
        };

    $arrat_order[] =    natsort($files);
    foreach($arrat_order as $value){
                   echo "
                        <div style='display: block'>
                        <a href= \"$dir/$value\">Watch \"$value\"</a>
                        </div>
                        ";

}
```

Comment: Please note that natsort() will return a boolean, not an array. Check the php doc here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php